# How to convert columns to rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, unpivot

I have a table like this one

```
RowNum | TranNo | nTotalSales | nBalance
   1   |    1   |    800      |    0
```

and I want to display it this way

```
RowNum      |   1
cTranNo     |   1
nTotalSales |  800
nBalance    |   0
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You tagged this as "pivot", which is correct.  Why not look at those questions?

Comment: All you need to do is search "pivot examples" https://www.google.com/search?q=pivot+examples

Comment: because i am to confused to the examples given in those question. so i was hoping to create my own. please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a complete working example, when you you do an `UNPIVOT`, which is what your are asking for, your 'value' types need to be of the same type, so cast them however you want. In my example, I have cast them all to VARCHAR(20):

```
DECLARE @bob TABLE
(
    RowNum INT,
    TranNo INT,
    nTotalSales INT,
    nBalance INT
);
INSERT INTO @bob(RowNum, TranNo, nTotalSales, nBalance)
VALUES(1, 1, 800, 0);


WITH T AS (
    SELECT CAST(RowNum      AS VARCHAR(20)) AS RowNum,
           CAST(TranNo      AS VARCHAR(20)) AS TranNo,
           CAST(nTotalSales AS VARCHAR(20)) AS nTotalSales,
           CAST(nBalance    AS VARCHAR(20)) AS nBalance
    FROM @bob
)

SELECT attribute, value
FROM T
UNPIVOT(value FOR attribute IN(RowNum, TranNo, nTotalSales, nBalance)) AS U;
```

Comment: interesting answer, but i have an error when i modify the 'with' area to this: "WITH T AS (select RowNum,cTranNo,nTotalSales,nBalance from tran_ar_si)"

Comment: "The type of column "cTranNo" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list." - thats the error message.

Comment: @dave, - `UNPIVOT` is what you're asking for, my friend. You don't need to use my `WITH T AS ( ... ` statement, that is just a working example. If you run my entire example by itself, then it will work fine. If you want to use with your table consider `WITH T AS (...` as your source table - let me know if you need further clarification

Comment: oh, i see what the problem is... hang on, I will edit my query. The problem is your 'value types' are conflicting with each other, like trying to mix dates w/ integers...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 'RowNum' TITLE, RowNum AS [VALUE]
FROM TABLE
UNION ALL
SELECT 'TranNo', TranNo
FROM TABLE
UNION ALL
SELECT 'nTotalSales', nTotalSales
FROM TABLE
UNION ALL
SELECT 'nBalance', nBalance
FROM TABLE
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not real fun, but here's one solution:

```
SELECT 'RowNum', RowNum FROM tbl
UNION
SELECT 'cTranNo', TranNo FROM tbl
UNION
SELECT 'nTotalSales', nTotalSales FROM tbl
UNION
SELECT 'nBalance', nBalance FROM tbl
```

That will turn the columns into rows. If you want each of the column-rows to be interlaced, you may need to introduce a record number along with some sorting.

That would look like this:

```
    SELECT 'RowNum' AS ColName, RowNum AS [Value], RowNum FROM tbl
    UNION
    SELECT 'cTranNo' AS ColName, TranNo, RowNum FROM tbl
    UNION
    SELECT 'nTotalSales' AS ColName, nTotalSales, RowNum FROM tbl
    UNION
    SELECT 'nBalance' AS ColName, nBalance, RowNum FROM tbl
    ORDER BY RowNum, ColName
```