# How to convert row to columns

Tags: sql

I have a table

```
empname LeaveFrom Leave To
Peter   11/05/2015 11/08/2015
peter   09/06/2015  09/08/2015
```

I want to make like this

```
EmpName LeaveFrom   LeaveTO      LeaveFrom LeaveTO
Peter   11/05/2015   11/08/2015  09/06/2015  09/08/2015
```

Comment: use pivot : http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/500811/Simple-Way-To-Use-Pivot-In-SQL-Query

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to converting columns to rows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9221922/how-to-converting-columns-to-rows)

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution, a self join:

```
select t1.empname, t1.LeaveFrom, t1.LeaveTo, t2.LeaveFrom, t2.LeaveTo
from tablename t1
  left join tablename t2 on t1.name = t1.name and t1.LeaveFrom < t2.LeaveFrom
```

(Doing a `LEFT JOIN` just in case some user has only 1 row.)